# SSRS series label property in chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

[image]

In SSRS I have a requirement to change the series label size, but haven't been able to.

Example: series label should have percentage and value the percentage should be larger in size and the value should be in small size

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported feature. Chart labels have a single set of formats.

One workaround would be to create a custom legend to the side of the chart. You could use a table to list the labels with the desired formats there. You may want to consider a different style of chart such as a bar chart to make it line up with the labels. That would make it easier to interpret.

Comment: @mangai Sorry this wasn't the answer you were hoping for. Given that it's the only answer, please mark it accordingly. Thanks.